# After moving the destination of my WordPress folder and renaming my project, I can't access wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I moved the destination of my WordPress folder in Finder and can no longer access wp-admin. I'm running MAMP and it's working, but I cannot access wp-admin and am receiving a 404 Not Found page.

My WordPress folder used to be part of Sites/HackerYou/Week7/WordPress. Now it's just Sites/WordPress. The project I'm working on reminds inside the WordPress folder and it has been renamed.

When I go to localhost:8888, that's where I'm receiving the Page not found notification. This is my WordPress so apologies if I'm not providing enough detail, please let me know if there's anything I can add to help you answer the question.

Edit: I have also changed my database name in phpMyAdmin and the wp-config file to the same name that I've given to my project folder.

Comment: Try using this https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV for your local WordPress development. I'm using this on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the path to your new directory in phpMyAdmin. Go to MAMP > Tools > phpMyAdmin. Select your database and click on wp_options. You need to change the path to your new directory for the "siteurl" and "home". The "home" option might be on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate folder mean, Follow these steps:

1) In your database change homeurl & siteurl

2) After migrate update your permalinks

3) Now also getting problem then open you config file

you can enable debug mode (i.e)  define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 it will show error statement.